# Why won't my new blog post display at the top of the blog?

Tags: joomla-3.6, featured-articles

My site is http://rockridgencpc.com, running Joomla 3.6.1.  I've used Joomla!for several years, and my standard method for creating a new blog entry is to create an article, flag it "Published" and "Featured", and save it. The category is "-News", which I've often used.  I don't link blog articles to a menu.

I created an article last Wednesday, and the article has never appeared at the top of the blog.  (I was out of town over the rest of the week.)  The system clearly knows it's there because the "Latest Articles" module lists it; but I want the text to show in the blog and it doesn't.  I created the new article on the same evening I upgraded to 3.6.1 - so I actually wrote it in 3.6.0.  But today I deleted the old article, and created a new article with the same text; and it won't display either.

I feel I must be missing something stupid, can anyone advise me?  I'm trying to announce a meeting that takes place in about 5 days. Have there been other reports like this about Joomla 3.6.1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is that your blog menu sorts articles by **Article order**. Before Joomla 3.6 (? - sorry, I can't find a reference right now), new articles where added to the **beginning** of the article order in your database, causing all existing articles to be "pushed" down. I think this was changed in the 3.6.0 update so that new articles where added at the end of your DB table, increasing the save speed on large sites since existing records would not have to be changed.

**Solution:**

Set your articles to be ordered by date - most recent articles first. The setting for how articles are ordered is found under article options (Shared tab), but can also be overridden by your menu item, so you might want to check both places.

[image: Article Options]

*Default setting for article order*

---

[image: Menu item settings]

*Menu item settings, found in the tab **Blog Layout** in your blog menu item. This overrides the default settings unless "Use Global" is selected.*

Comment: You're quite right.  I had asked the same question in a couple of places, and Joomlashack (which supports the style we bought) responded first.  They didn't explain the changes as clearly as you did, and I appreciate the clarity, thank you very much.  I update this blog infrequently, and I believe the last update may actually have been on 3.5.x, which is why I haven't had the problem before.  Sigh.

Comment: I'm happy to hear that. There was some discussion whether this was a bug or a feature, but as long as you want the most recent articles displayed first, it's best to use date for sorting.

Comment: One problem I've experienced with "order by date" is that it literally means "date", not date/time as one would expect if one is a programmer. So for two articles with the same date but different times the times are ignored and the ordering may not be what you expect.